# Search entire row and return column name in ms access using function

Tags: function, ms-access, vba

Could use a little help. Previously I have been using IIF statements to get this output but there are limitations to IIF and now am looking for a function (In MS Access) to meet the requirement.

Challenge:  Need to search a row for a criteria (e.g. Title 00\Question..), if/when a match is found it returns the column name using a function withing a query (e.g. FieldCategorization(Title 00\Question).  Click on links below to see table and desired output

**Microsoft access table:**

[image: Microsoft access table]

**Desired output from query:**

[image: Desired output from query]

What I have so far searches the entire table, it doesn't seach a row-per-row basis:

```
Public Function FieldCategorization(TblName As String, Criteria As Long) As String
    Set dbs = CurrentDb
    Set rs = dbs.OpenRecordset(TblName)
    Dim fld As DAO.Field

    ' MyValue = 224803 ' T00 = Title 00\Question\First Name Text
    ' MyValue = 224814 ' AB00 = Abbreviation 00
    MyValue = Criteria

    'MsgBox "TblName: " & TblName & vbCrLf & "Criteria: " & Criteria

    rs.MoveFirst
    ' Move through each row in the recordset
    'Do While Not rs.EOF
        For Each fld In rs.Fields
            If fld = MyValue Then
                FieldCategorization = fld.Name
            End If
        Next fld
    rs.MoveNext
    'Loop

End Function
```

Comment: What did your IIF look like?

Comment: All you need is two similar _IIf_ expressions like: `Title 00: IIf(Left([T_Val_00_AV], 8)="Title 00", "T_Val_00_AV", IIf(Left([T_Val_01_AV], 8)="Title 00", "T_Val_01_AV",  ...etc. .. )))))))`. Sorry, too lazy to spell all this out.

Comment: The iif statement was vary simular.  However, the table is more than 14 columns and thus hits the limitation of iif statement driving the need for a function solution.

Comment: Your question is very confusing. I have no idea how you are generating your desired result. Please add sample data and expected result as text, using http://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to treat a database like a spreadsheet.  Would be much easier in a normalised database (can use native queries) or in a spreadsheet (can use VBA to search "rows" and "columns").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just did something similar today.  The example below is super simplified, but I think it has all the elements you're looking for.

```
    dim fld as fields
    dim rst, rstW as recordset

    MyValue = "Title 00\Question"

    Set dbs = currentdB
    Set rst = dbs.openrecordset ("table1")
    Set rstW = dbs.openrecordset  ("table2")

    rst.movefirst
    Do while not rst.eof
       for each fld in rst.fields
           if me(fld.name) = MyValue then
               rstW.addnew
               rstW!Title00 = fld.name
               rstW.update
           end if
       next fld
       rst.movenext
   Loop
```

Comment: geeFlo,  Thank you for the input.  I am not looking to create a table, only search a row and return the name of column (on a per row basis) when the seach criteria is found.  For example, is a good start but it is trying to process the hole table, not a row.

Comment: The WHILE loop should take you through the entire table (all records)    The FOR LOOP iterate through each field.  If you have more values to search, just expand the IF statement

Comment: If you only need the row,  then remove the while loop

Comment: geeFlo, super helpful guidance.  I'm still stuck (thank you for your patience).  ultimately need to use the function multiple times within a query  for example (in the query):    FieldCategorization("TblName" )

Comment: for example (in the query): 
Title 00: FieldCategorization("TblName", "Title 00\Question") 
Abbreviation 00: FieldCategorization("TblName", "Abbreviation 00") 

the query (Taking the while loop out of the function) is at "Title 00" returning "T_Val_00_AV" for all fields (incorrect, some should be "T_Val_03_AV" based on the example above) and then "Abbreviation 00" column is null

Comment: geeFlo, 99% sure (updated original post, removed while loop) that the function is searching the entire table until it finds a match vs searching a row and stoping.

Comment: The FOR NEXT will go through each field in your table, within whichever record you have active.   If you're calling the record from outside the procedure then you don't need to move the recordset.  I.e. it's only searching one row aka record.   However you need to use the "writing" recordset to create your second table.   Reread and debug the code I gave you and use the parts that help you.

Comment: gleeFlo, thank you so much for walking me through this!